# Is it possible to connect an Apple Thunderbolt Display to a Windows Desktop?

Tags: windows, desktop-computer, thunderbolt

We have an Apple Thunderbolt Display and a HP Pavilion Desktop 590. I was wondering whether there is anyway to connect the Thunderbolt Display with a Desktop using some adapters?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a thunderbolt card for your PC.

Comment: Have not tried it, but see this HDMI-to-Mini DisplayPort adapter, or similar. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003LGOWNQ

Comment: Basically, YMMV. The linked question does not have an accepted answer, but the answers that have been posted are good and contain information that will answer your question.